# smart gwt 5.0 widgets + GWT 2.7.0 doesn't show up on superdev mode

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, smartgwt

I am using Eclipse Luna,created project with Google plugin, and added SmartGwt LGPL 5.0 created some test files, but widgets are not displayed at all. Tried all solution from google search, but doesn't fix anything. Here the gwt.xml file code

```
<module rename-to='test'>
   <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
   <inherits name='com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoScript'/> 
   <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> 

  <entry-point class='org.test.client.Test'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->

</module>
```

Test.java class sample code is here:

```
public class Test implements EntryPoint {
        public void onModuleLoad() {
        HLayout l = new HLayout();
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setTitle("Testing it is smartgwt please run!");
        btn.setText("gwt button");
        l.addMember(btn);
        RootPanel.get().add(l);
//      //l.draw();

    }
}
```

Test.html file code is here:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css">
    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>
    <script>var isomorphicDir = "test/sc/"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="test/test.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried declaring the smartGWT files in the host page:

```
<script src="assetservicing/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js">          </script>
<script src="assetservicing/sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js">    </script>
<script src="assetservicing/sc/modules/ISC_Containers.js">    </script>
<script src="assetservicing/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js">         </script>
<script src="assetservicing/sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js">         </script>
<script src="assetservicing/sc/modules/ISC_RichTextEditor.js"></script>
<script src="assetservicing/sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js">      </script>
<script src="assetservicing/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js">   </script>

<script src="assetservicing/sc/skins/Enterprise/load_skin.js">   </script>
```